# A function uses two parameters: a variable and a string with the same name. Reduce them to one parameter?

Tags: javascript, css, function, animation, parameters

I created a function to make it easy to add animations to any element with a set of key parameters such as: *animation-name* and *animation-duration*, etc. Here is the function below:

```
addAnimation( h1, 'blur', '50s', '0s', 'ease' );
```

My question has to do with a smaller function used in the former. It updates the animation properties and takes 3 parameters *two of which have the same exact name, only 1 is a variable and 1 is a string*:

```
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'name', name ); 
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'duration', duration );
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'delay', delay ); 
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'timing', timing );
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'fill', fill );
```

See the redundancy? `'name', name`, `'duration', duration`, etc. I know this isn't a major problem most developers will worry about but I'm curious to learn the ins and outs of what JavaScript can do. Is there a way to reduce my `updateAnimationProperties` function to only use 2 parameters total by reducing the 2 repetitive ones into one?

**Full code below**

```js
//\ \ \ \ \ \ \ UPDATE ANIMATION PROPERTIES / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
function updateAnimationProperties( element, property, value ){
  var style = element.style,
      property = 'animation' + property.charAt( 0 ).toUpperCase() + 
                  property.slice( 1 );
  
  if( style[ property ] === '' ){
    style[ property ] = value;
  }
  else {
    style[ property ] += ', ' + value;
  }  
}
/// / / / / / / UPDATE ANIMATION PROPERTIES \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \

//\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ADD ANIMATION / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
function addAnimation( 
  element, name, duration, delay, timing, fill 
){    
  element.classList.add( 'animation' );
  
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'name', name ); 
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'duration', duration );  //default = 1s
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'delay', delay );  //default = 0s
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'timing', timing );  //default = ease
  updateAnimationProperties( element, 'fill', fill );  //default = forwards);
}
/// / / / / / / / / / ADD ANIMATION \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \

var h1 = document.querySelector( 'h1' );

addAnimation( h1, 'blur', '50s', '0s', 'ease' );
addAnimation( h1, 'fade', '2s', '1s', 'ease' );
addAnimation( h1, 'shrink', '20s', '0s', 'ease' );
```

```css
/* \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION DEFINITIONS / / / / / / / / / / / / / */
.animation {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.blur {
  animation-name: blur;
}
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
}
.shrink {
  animation-name: shrink;
}

/*\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ANIMATION KEYFRAMES / / / / / / / / / / / / / /*/
@keyframes blur {
  100% {
    filter: blur( 5rem );
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes shrink {
  100% {
    transform: scale( 0 );
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="display: inline-block; font-family: sans-seirf; font-weight: normal">
  Blur me, fade me, and shrink me
</h1>
```

---

**RECAP**

In functions like this:

`someFunction( 'value', value )` how can I turn this into

`someFunction( value )` or `someFunction( 'value' )`.

Specifically in relation to my code above?

Comment: That would be an anti-optimization. The 2 params are 2 different things and should remain separate. (Conceivably) you could write some logic in the function to parse out the property name from the variable name, but that would be relying on strict variable naming convention. It is a bad idea.

Comment: The variable you have called `name` could just as well have been named `foo` then your call would be `updateAnimationProperties( element, 'name', foo );` The string and the var don't match now.  Your call could be made as `updateAnimationProperties( document.getElementById('thing', 'duration', '0.5s' );` where you're not even passing a variable, what then?

Comment: @StephenP The goal here I guess is to use less parameters to have less code, less clutter, and more readability. In this particular function the and for this particular app. the values will always be consistently matched like this. Is it bad practice?

Comment: @mhatch even for a predictable very small program? Are you telling me this will slow the overall app down, even slightly?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the CSS and HTML are needed for this question. Removing them would make it easier to read.

Comment: @FrankModica for a newb like me it is so much easier to see actual examples with results affecting real elements in a page than just looking at straight JavaScript code. At the end of my question I gave a simplified example to make it easier to see what I'm asking on the JavaScript side of things. I formatted my question like this for that reason.

Comment: @savant I was not talking in terms of speed I was talking in terms of code efficiency as it relates to non-repetition. What the OP seems to be trying to achieve. This is still a very, very bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ES6 [Object Literal Property Value Shorthand](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand) you can have the function accept an object and then the call would look like `updateAnimationProperties( element, {name});` then in the function you can get the object key and value

```
function updateAnimationProperties(element, obj) {
  let key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  let value = obj[key];
  // whatever else the function does with the values
  //...
}
```

Comment: I was typing a similar answer when Nayish beat me to it with his good answer above. The one other thing I'd add is that with ES6 you can explicitly name the expected keys in your function declaration, e.g. function updateAnimationProperties({element, name, duration, delay, timing, fill}) if you prefer that more explicit style.

Comment: Good answer @Nayish -- I think it would be better if you also added examples of calling it `updateAnimationProperties(e, { 'name':name, 'duration':duration });` etc.